# Make element move by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am trying to make a webpage where when you click a link, the link moves diagonally every 100 milliseconds.**

So I have my Javascript, but right now when I click the link nothing happens

*Also, does anyone know of a Javascript IDE I can use to make sure I have no errors in my code?*

PS: Does anyone know why my  elements dont stretch to fit the whole 200px by 200px of the div element? The links are only small when they should be the same width as their parent div element.

**Edited with new advice, although still wont move.**

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
<!--
    var block         = null;
    var clockStep     = null;
    var index         = 0;
    var maxIndex      = 6;
    var x             = 0;
    var y             = 0;
    var timerInterval = 100;  // milliseconds
    var xPos          = null;
    var yPos          = null;

    function moveBlock()
    {
        if ( index < 0 || index >= maxIndex || block == null || clockStep == null ) 
        { 
            clearInterval( clockStep );
            return;
        }

        block.style.left = xPos[index] + "px";
        block.style.top  = yPos[index] + "px";
        index++;
    }

    function onBlockClick( blockID )
    {
        if ( clockStep != null )
        {
            return;
        }

        block = document.getElementById( blockID );
        index = 0;
        x = parseInt( block.style.left, 10 );
        y = parseInt( block.style.top, 10 );
        xPos  = new Array( x+10, x+20, x+30, x+40, x+50, x+60 );
        yPos  = new Array( y-10, y-20, y-30, y-40, y-50, y-60 );

        clockStep = self.SetInterval( moveBlock(), timerInterval );
    }
-->
</script>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    <!--
    @import url("styles.css");

    #blockMenu { z-index: 0; width: 650px; height: 600px; background-color: blue; padding: 0; }

    #block1 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 10px;  left: 10px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }
    #block2 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 50px; left: 220px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }
    #block3 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 50px; left: 440px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }
    #block4 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 600px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }

    #block1 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #block2 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #block3 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #block4 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

    #block1 a:hover { background-color: green; }
    #block2 a:hover { background-color: green; }
    #block3 a:hover { background-color: green; }
    #block4 a:hover { background-color: green; }

    #block1 a:active { background-color: yellow; }
    #block2 a:active { background-color: yellow; }
    #block3 a:active { background-color: yellow; }
    #block4 a:active { background-color: yellow; }

    -->
</style>
```

Comment: Use http://www.jslint.com/ to check your JS code. And watch all videos from Douglas Crockford on http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

Comment: Regarding your IDE/Error checking question, there are two possible solutions
1)You can use an IDE that performs syntax and semantics checking. These are generally quite large and are often Eclipse-based. Aptana is good one.
2)You can use jslint to perform basic syntax checking. This will not check your code logically, but it will catch a good majority of simple errors. Many text editors (notepad++, textmate, etc) have modules or plugins which can integrate jslint functionality right into the editor.

Comment: KomodoEdit is free and is awesome, and will JSLint your code as you type. Your "a" elements need to be set to display:block so you can set their size.

Comment: I'm gonna stop helping noobs if I can't get a simple vote-up from them. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors needed to fix**

To fill the width of the `div` elements, the `a` elements need to be `display: block;` not their default `display: inline;`.

Knowing runtime errors is more important in my opinion, and IDEs don't catch DOM errors or anything more complex than syntax; use the error logging in your browser (Firefox's is called Error Console). That'll also catch in-development errors like syntax errors.

This is the most important point to stress: `block.style.left` and `block.style.top` are not just numbers with implicit pixel values in them. Setting it to a number without a unit suffix will do absolutely nothing. You need to add `%` or `px` or whatever unit when setting `left` and `top`.

When getting the current value, as in `var x = ...` and `var y = ...`, you need to `Number()` manually to get the numeric portion of the string.

Also, I believe you meant `|| block == null`, not `=`, which would set `block` to `null`.

**Tips**

You can use `moveBlock` instead of `"moveBlock();"` as an argument to `setTimeout`. This avoids parsing the string into code, and avoids scope problems (though not in this example as `moveBlock` is global).

I know that you have an array of values, where both `x` and `y` move 10 each time. I assume you want to move at a 45 degree angle. If so, this won't work as you expect even after fixing all the errors as `x` is  percentage and `y` is in pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the replies: Made the changes you suggested :) Still not having luck tho. **Edit: cant post my javascript in this comment thingie :P**

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your x and y above like your other variables. It may work but its confusing.

in your setTimeout, use moveBlock, not "moveBlock()" - it will save the step of evaluating your string into code.

block.style.left will return a string that includes "px" - it won't be a number. You can do:

```
x = Number(x);
//or 
x = parseInt(x, 10);
```

When you set the position, remember to add the "px":

```
block.style.left = xPos[index] + "px";
```

EDIT:

Ok, the key problem is 'style.left' is not reading because it was set with CSS and not the style object. I use my library to get the style which runs through a few scenarios and catches that automatically. So change these lines to (this may not be exactly correct but will get things moving):

```
x = parseInt( node.style.left, 10 ) || 0;
y = parseInt( node.style.top, 10 ) || 0;
```

Also, this is wrong (you never declared 'self', and you don't need it here anyway; JS is case sensitive, SetInterval is not capped; pass the **function**, not the **function result**):

```
clockStep = self.SetInterval( moveBlock(), timerInterval ); // <-- result of moveBlock
// change to:
 clockStep = setInterval( moveBlock, timerInterval );  // <-- the function moveBlock
```

During dev, you should remove the if() statements that could have been blocking the code and just put a simple count--; in there. It's really hard to debug code when you have literally 20 things wrong. Write a line, test. Write a line, test.

You have HTML comments in the script and style blocks. This is from 1998. While they don't hurt anything intact, in the past I've accidentally edited my code and removed one of them, and this will throw everything out of whack - your IDE, the browser - because they won't know what's wrong and you won't get a good error message.

LANGUAGE="JavaScript" is no longer used and is a waste of bytes.

To help speed development add this line:

```
window.onloadfunction(){
    onBlockClick('block1')
}
```

That will execute your code right away for testing and you don't have to click every time.

Finally, I ***highly recommend*** you use ***Firefox and Firebug***. Developing without it is like trying to build a ship in a bottle with boxing gloves. Using console.log(block.style.left) would have shown you it was not set. The error messages would have told you SetInterval and moveBlock() was incorrect. You do need to remember to remove the console.logs before production though. *or*... (shameless plug)... use my JavaScript Console Fix library which will do that for you: http://clubajax.org/javascript-console-fix-v2-now-with-ios/